# Is it haram to develop social apps

Tags: practical-islam, sharia, internet

Im a developer,sometimes i get some ideas like why don,t i make a website or app like Facebook or Instagram ,but the other side i thing ,when people will use this apps they can post anything* ya there can be report buttons for such post ,and there can also be education and islamic posts but there can also be haram posts..

Comment: I don't think it's haram. But you should make rules that people can't post vulgar and haram posts. And try to respond to all the reports. After all of this even if someone did post haram stuff you will be not responsible. It's like, if someone buy a knife and use it to harm others, the seller will not be responsible for that. Because it can be used for good or bad purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a beginner developer myself,

I can say it isn’t haram.
Whatever they post is on them. Not you, don’t hold yourself responsible. You can’t necessarily control what people post, but you can set up guidelines on what you are allowed to post and what you are not allowed.

You could implement a feature similar to what Instagram has that automatically deletes a photo that goes against their terms of service. So you don’t really have to report all the way.
Plus, there’s many loyal people out there that do the good deed and report.

If you’re worried people may post haram things, you can make an Islamic based social media app if you’d like.

But that’s like asking, “is it haram to use a phone/computer? Because when you use a phone/computer, you’re accessed to anything—haram or halal. Phones/computers also contain websites and videos of Islamic lectures.”

In the end, there’s no real way of escaping haram and halal in anything. There’s a platform of both in technology nowadays. It’s just on you what you choose.

However, if you strictly plan to develop an app that’s for haram use, that’s an obvious yes.

But you’re intentions aren’t that, and I don’t see anything wrong with making a social media like app.